# Function local variable same address in every call

Tags: c, memory

I was trying to find a bug in a code likes this:

```
char *** read_set(char * filename)
{
  int ch;
  while(ch!=EOF)
  {
    //code...
  }
    //mode code...
}
```

In the first call it was working as expected but in the second call ch was EOF(-1). Of course i should have initialized it,but i didnt expect that the local variable would be assigned the same adress. Is this something that happens always or is it dependent on the os/compiler etc?

Comment: Consider it undefined behaviour to read an uninitialized integer (even though strictly speaking it may only be "indeterminate"); don't do it. Write correct programs.

Comment: Using an uninitialized variable is always undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal, especially if you call the function from the same caller many times, e.g.

```
read_set("foo");
read_set("bar");
read_set("baz");
```

or

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  read_set(filenames[i]);
}
```

The stack contains the return address, the frame pointer, the local variables, the parameter values and the temporary values of each active function call (starting from `main`). It's quite common that all these have a fixed size for each function, so if function A() needs 40 bytes on the stack, function B() needs 20 bytes and function C() needs 1000 bytes, then in the following two situations the local variables (e.g. `&ch`) of read_set are usually on the same address:

1. main() calls C(), C() calls B(), B() calls B() again, the inner B() calls read_set().
2. main() calls C(), C() calls A(), A() calls read_set().

Please note that depending on the compiler and on the architecture you may get different addresses. But getting the same address is not unusual.

Please note that some security features such as address space randomization may give you different addresses every time you run the program again. But within the same run, you get the same addresses.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration:

```
int ch;
```

is equivalent to:

```
auto int ch;
```

The `auto` part is implied; being default when declaring variables inside a function.  `auto` variables are stored on the process stack, and the memory they occupy on the stack is used for other purposes upon returning from the function.  Hence, the `scope` of auto variables is limited to the moment the function is executed.

The address of such an `auto` (stack based) variable is not consistent from one call of the function to the next.  It depends on what has been placed on (or pulled from) the stack prior to calling the function.

---

It is possible to declare a variable which will keep its value from one call of the function to the next; but that variable would not be stored on the stack.  Do declare such a variable, it must be switched from the default `auto` type, to the `static` type:

```
 static int ch;
```

And you are correct; you should initialize such a variable with an initial value:

```
 static int ch = 0;
```

Declaring a static variable within a function causes the compiler to give that variable it's own permanent memory location for the duration of the program's execution.  Hence, it's address will not change from one call of the function to the next.